# Paypal Reauth failing- DCC_REAUTHORIZATION_NOT_ALLOWED

Tags: java, api, rest, paypal

We are facing issue while doing reauth with Paypal API's.Please help if someone has encountered with this error. We have created one authorization few days back and now we are trying to do the re-auth for this using following

```
authorization= Authorization.get(accessToken, "8EU99222SR844720V");

Amount amount = new Amount();

amount.setCurrency("USD").setTotal("10");

authorization.setAmount(amount);

Authorization reauthorization = authorization.reauthorize(accessToken);
```

We are getting this error:

```
SEVERE: Error code : 500 with response : {"name":"**DCC_REAUTHORIZATION_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"Reauthorization not allowed for this product**.","information_link":"https:// developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DCC_REAUTHORIZATION_NOT_ALLOWED","debug_id":"2d9b8f10ed53c"}
Exception in thread "main" com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalRESTException: Error code : 500 with response : {"name":"DCC_REAUTHORIZATION_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"Reauthorization not allowed for this product.","information_link":"https:// developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DCC_REAUTHORIZATION_NOT_ALLOWED","debug_id":"2d9b8f10ed53c"}
 at com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:329)
 at com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:245)
 at com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalResource.configureAndExecute(PayPalResource.java:191)
 at com.paypal.api.payments.Authorization.reauthorize(Authorization.java:387)
 at com.paypal.api.payments.Authorization.reauthorize(Authorization.java:366)
 at com.paypal.api.payments.AuthorizationTestCase.testGetAuthorization(AuthorizationTestCase.java:87)
 at com.paypal.api.payments.AuthorizationTestCase.main(AuthorizationTestCase.java:66)
Caused by: com.paypal.exception.HttpErrorException: Error code : 500 with response : {"name":"DCC_REAUTHORIZATION_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"Reauthorization not allowed for this product.","information_link":"https:// developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DCC_REAUTHORIZATION_NOT_ALLOWED","debug_id":"2d9b8f10ed53c"}
 at com.paypal.core.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:108)
 at com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalResource.execute(PayPalResource.java:321)
 ... 6 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https:// api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/8EU99222SR844720V/reauthorize
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1491)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1485)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
 at com.paypal.core.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:78)
 ... 7 more
 Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/authorization/8EU99222SR844720V/reauthorize
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
 at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
 at com.paypal.core.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:77)
 ... 7 more
```

Comment: few more authorization ID's we tried-5C331170EU4352306, 59S50842PT224043B

Answer (score 0):

From the [REST API Developers Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#reauthorize-a-payment): Note: You can only reauthorize PayPal account payments.

This means you cannot reauthorize Direct Credit Card (DCC) payments.